# Como faço um simples "ping" em sites externos retornando o status: 200, 400

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, requisição

Sou iniciante no **JavaScript**, **AngularJS** e **jQuery**. Já quebrei a cabeça aqui e não consegui resolver a seguinte solução usando como base o *JavaScript*:

Quero fazer uma lista dos sites que desenvolvi, mostrando seus status em tempo real usando JavaScript - se estão online adiciono uma classe na `div` com uma cor verde, senão utilizo outra cor.

'Soluções' que encontrei, mas que não deram certo:

- `Fetch_API`: Utilizei, mas nem todos os sites retornavam um objeto **json** com o status do site.
- `XMLHttpRequest()`: Pesquisei sobre, mas no console diz estar obsoleto usar isso.

Não sei se essas soluções são das melhores. A ideia é simples: o script faz uma solicitação para o site que quero e retorna o status dele se é 200(ok), 500, 400 ou outro e eu vou manipular meu front-end de acordo com o resultado.

Comment: Veja se o exemplo abaixo te ajuda.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282151/is-it-possible-to-ping-a-server-from-javascript

Comment: Ok Ismael, ou dar uma olhada lá agora... Obrigado!

Comment: Olá Ismael, infelizmente não funcionou...

Comment: Existe uma alternativa para saber se é 200 ou se é diferente de 200, sem obter o código exato, ou seja pode ser 400, 500... Não sei se isso seria suficiente para o seu caso.

Comment: Olá Inkeliz, seria interessante também.

Answer (score 3):

Infelizmente não há maneira de implementar uma solução assim utilizando *apenas* Angular (ou qualquer outra tecnologia client-side, como jQuery) por causa da [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), ou *política de mesma origem*.

Você pode utilizar [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), adicionando o domínio onde sua ferramenta de verificação está sendo executada a todas as [white-lists](http://blog.blakesimpson.co.uk/read/64-apache-configure-cors-headers-for-whitelist-domains) de seus sites, para permitir que o Angular tenha acesso a recursos de seus domínios individuais.

Caso você não tenha permissões de manipulação das *white-lists* você pode ainda implementar uma solução a  ser executada [a partir de um servidor](https://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html), onde uma conexão direta pode ser estabelecida - e o estado das aplicações remotas avaliadas individualmente.

Answer (score 0):

Opa Obrigado pelo guia. Acabei encontrando uma solução em **jQuery**, basicamente ele é um serviço externo onde ele solicita o site que eu quero consultar e retorna um objeto **json** com as informações do site (variavel.status) ou todo o **Html** do site.

Encontrei uma solução também em **PHP** que faz algo semelhante, mas que reúne mais informações e não precisa de um serviço externo. Vou deixar o código aqui para quem tem que construir uma solução semelhante.

Em JavaScript:

```js
  $.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://www.facebook.com') + '&callback=?', function(data){
   if(data){
    console.log(data.status);
   }else{
    return("servidor offline");
   }
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Angular Curl</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <h3 style="text-align: center">Mostre o Console para ver o Retorno do Objeto</h3>

</body>
</html>
```

E abaixo em PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ping Site</title>
</head>
<body>


<?php

    function curl_info($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    // curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );

    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $info = curl_getinfo( $ch );

    return $info;
    }

    $site = 'http://www.honda.com/';
    $info = curl_info( $site );

    if( $info['http_code']==200 || $info['http_code']==302 || $info['http_code']==301) {
        echo '<u>'.$site . "</u> - <b style='color:lightgreen; font-size: 18px; text-transform: uppercase'>está no ar!!</b><br />";
        var_dump($info);
    } else {
        echo '<u>'.$site . "</u> - <b style='color:red; font-size: 18px; text-transform: uppercase'>está fora do ar!!</b><br />";
        var_dump($info);
    }
?>

</body>
</html>
```